# Adding an Event Handler to a Newly Created Window using C++

Tags: c++, windows, event-handling, winapi

How do I add an event-handler to a newly created window using C++?

```
_hWnd = CreateWindow( NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
```

It is a dummy window that is intended to do nothing but wait for the `WM_DEVICECHANGE` event and is to be registered using `RegisterDeviceNotification`.  How do I attach the event-handler to this window?  I am using Visual Studio 2008.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by setting the window procedure with `SetWindowLongPtr` and the `GWL_WNDPROC` flag.

```
SetWindowLongPtr(_hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, myWndProc);
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is by far easier than trying to setup `RegisterClass`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to associate a window procedure with a window class using [`RegisterClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633586%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and then create your window using this class. It is the window procedure which handles *all* messages - there is no "event handler" mechanism in Win32.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others have said, when creating a hidden window just to receive messages, consider using `CreateWindowEx()` instead, with its `hWndParent` parameter set to `HWND_MESSAGE`.  See [MSDN for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599.aspx#message_only).

Answer (score 0):

At least normally, you first call [`RegisterClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633586%28VS.85%29.aspx), which specifies the window proc for that class of windows. You then specify the class when you call [`CreateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You may not have to create separate window just for handling this message.

I mention this because most windows applications already have a window created, and you merely need to add processing for the WM_DEVICECHANGE message to the window procedure of your main window.

If you application is running as a Windows Service (daemon), you can also receive device change notifications in your [service control handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683241%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

If your application is a console mode application, you can [fetch the handle to it's window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683175%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [subclass it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633570%28VS.85%29.aspxa), adding processing for the  WM_DEVICECHANGE message.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, but, unfortunately, this this is for a low-level DLL, and the window handle is not accessible, which is why I'm working on making a dummy window to receive/handle this event.

Comment: Got it.  In such cases, you'll have to be mindful of the thread that you associate with your dummy window.  That is, if you're creating this window in the context of some sort of callback into your DLL, you need to be certain that the calling thread can handle having a message pump associated with it.